# Differentiations of matrix algebra are inner

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can one prove that all differentiations of (associative) matrix algebra over a field are inner? I tried to calculate dimensions, but stuck.

Comment: http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/derivations-of-central-simple-algebras/